# How to construct an Entity Framework query that returns recursive foreign-key relationships

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Suppose that I have a table `Product`

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PersonId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SupervisorId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(Id)
)
```

`Person` is a rather vanilla example of a table that references itself.

Suppose that I want to query my `Product` table and populate a class with the relavant product information, as well as the ID, name, and supervisor, of every person in the chain of command regarding that product.

Suppose that I naively write the following C# (assuming I'm using AutoMapper, as well):

```
var dbQuery = context.Products;
var entities = dbQuery.ToArray();
var products = Mapper.Map(entities);
```

This will work okay only so long as the number of products is small.  This is because Entity Framework will initially only query the `Product` table, and only fill in the Person entities as they are queried.  Using something like AutoMapper here is essentially like doing SQL in a loop, and causes performance issues when the number of rows in `Product` becomes large.

So suppose instead, I write this:

```
var dbQuery = context.Products.Include(x => x.Person);
var entities = dbQuery.ToArray();
var products = Mapper.Map(entities);
```

Now, I'm including the first `Person` row associated with a row in `Product`, but it's still problematic because each Person has one or more supervisors to be queried.

Is there some way I can tell Entity Framework to recursively query my database so that I get the entire command-chain of people and supervisors associated with a single product so that when AutoMapper tries to map these onto my classes, no new queries are required?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2738#issuecomment-409990374

Comment: EF has no way to determine the number of self joins required other than the depth of the .Include statements. Potentially you could write a recursive extension method to check wether there are entities in the navigation property before including and going one layer deeper, but that might be a big performance hit.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, the whole point of my question is to avoid having to repeatedly check and go deeper one layer at a time *because* of the performance hit associated with repeated queries to the data source, especially in a situation where this is done for a large array of `Product` records.  I can't be the first one to face this.